# Why is VSCode using Cygwin to build and execute my CPP programs?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I downloaded and installed MinGW under `C:\MinGw` and installed **g++** and **gcc**.

If I run `g++ --version` I get:

```
g++.exe (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE
```

If I run `gcc --version`, I get:

```
gcc (GCC) 11.3.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying 
conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR 
A PARTICULAR PURPOSE
```

I'm trying to run a simple **helloworld.cpp** file from VSCode:

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
}
```

I've edited the **c_cpp_properties.json** file as follows:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "C:\\MinGW\\include"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

But when I go and build/run the file, I get the following:

```
Starting build...
C:\cygwin64\bin\cpp.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g C:\Users\Pippo\Desktop\Programming\CPP\helloworld.cpp -o C:\Users\Pippo\Desktop\Programming\CPP\helloworld.exe
cpp: fatal error: cannot execute 'cc1plus': spawn: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

Build finished with error(s).
```

Why is this failing? And why am I seeing Cygwin being called??

**EDIT (more stuff I don't get):**

The behaviour I showed before happens when I click on *Run C/C++ File*

[image]

But when I click on *Run Code* it works (and it calls g++):

[image]

**EDIT (@Yakk - Adam Nevraumont answer):** Nope, Cygwin is after g++ in my env vars:

[image]

Comment: You need to set the compiler in the VS Code options. `c_cpp_properties.json` is just for linting.

Comment: 6 is reeeeally old. Current one is 12. you can install it via msys2

Comment: Probably because you have Cygwin in the PATH. Unstall your MinGW *and* Cygwin (the former is outdated, the latter you probably don't need), or at least remove them from PATH. Install [MSYS2 as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075), and use it to install an up-to-date GCC.

Comment: There is `tasks.json` which is separate from `c_cpp_properties.json` and should have some of the relevant settings in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VSCode uses a completely separate tool chain for compiling and for linting and syntax highlighting and similar.

`c_cpp_properties.json` isn't for compiling.

It gets the compiler typically from your `PATH`.  See [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp).

Your build task is probably set to the compiler g++, and the first one on the search path (the PATH environment variable) is Cygwin's g++.  Alternatively, it can be hard coded in `tasks.json`.

Comment: that's not  the case, look at my edit pls

Comment: @IDK The link I provided mentions build tasks.  Those might be good for you to look at.

Comment: yep, I edited the tasks.json file. That's where the path to cygwin was coming from. Thanks

Comment: @IDK `tasks.json` added to answer for the next person cursed with using VSCode!